# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{1.2}+...+\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2^n}\right)}{n.\left(n+1\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $\{s_n\}$ of of real numbers given by  $$s_n=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{1.2}+\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2^n}\right)}{2.3}+...+\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2^n}\right)}{n.\left(n+1\right)}.$$ Evaluate the limit of the following.

**My Try**

$|s_n|\leq \frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{2.3}+...+\frac{1}{n.\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}=1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Taking limits on the both side. We can say $|s_n|\leq 1$. Also $s_{n+1}-s_n=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{2^n}\right)}{n.\left(n+1\right)}\geq 0.$ So, it is an increasing sequence of real numbers. Hence, it converges to $1$. Am I correct?

Comment: What do you mean by $n.(n+1)$ when $n+1>9$?

Comment: @MiloMoses I think $a.b = a\times b $

Comment: Your try is certainly not correct. Using that $\sin(\pi/2^n) \leq \pi/2^n$, you can bound $$ s_n \leq \frac12 + \frac16 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{\pi}{2^n} = \frac12 + \frac{\pi}{12} < 1.$$

Comment: Product of $n$ and $(n+1)$@MiloMoses

Comment: @WillieWong where is the mistake sir?

Comment: A bounded increasing sequence is guaranteed to converge to some number that is no more than the upper bound, but there is no reason why it must converge to the upper bound. (For example, any increasing sequence bounded by 1 is also an increasing sequence bounded by 2; it cannot converge both to 1 and to 2.)

Comment: To put it slightly differently: if you want to apply the sandwich theorem, you need two pieces of bread.